# Matrices and its properties and operations

Tags: matrices

Let A be an n*n matrix having elements as (aij) where i is the number of row and j is the number of column such that aij is equal to 0 whenever i is greater than or equal to j. I have to prove that matrix A of order n is a zero matrix.

Comment: What about $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: But it is not a zero matrix. I need to prove it a zero matrix.

Comment: Well, you see that this matrix meets your conditions, but isn't the zero matrix. So, the claim is (obviously) false.

Comment: Ok, by "the matrix $A$ of order $n$" you mean $A^n$...

Comment: yes. I meant same.

Answer (score 0):

You can think your matrix $A$ as the matrix  of a linear application $f$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the canonical basis $\mathcal{C}=(e_1,\dots,e_n)$. Then, if you note $F_r=\mathrm{span}(e_1,\dots,e_r)$ for $r\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $F_0=\{0_{\mathbb{R}^n}\},$ note that $f$ maps $F_{r}$ to $F_{r-1}$ for all $r\in\{1,\dots,n\}.$ As $A^n$ is the matrix of the linear application $f^n$ in the canonical basis, we show that $f^n=0_{\mathcal{L}(E)}$ and finally $A^n=0_{\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})}.$